# Datagridview with combobox cannot fill in

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Have datagridview which contains 4 columns created manually in datagridview creator. 1st, 2nd and 3rd columns are just textbox columns but the last one is marked as comboboxcolumn. On my form i have button, when user clicks it new row is add to datagridview. For first three columns data is filled up from some variables, and the last combobox column should be filled up for user from datasource so he could select his value out of it. The problem is i have problems with this combobox column and so far couldn't fill it in. This is my actual code

```
Private Sub myButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddMatType.Click

Dim dt as DataTable
dt = New Variation().GetAll() 'returning Ids and Names

              Dim cbo = CType(dgvMaterials.Columns(3), DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)
              cbo.Items.AddRange(dt.AsEnumerable().Select(Function(s) s.Field(Of String)("Name")).ToArray())

            try
              Dim rodzajID as String = TreeMaterials.SelectedValue
              Dim rodzajName as string = TreeMaterials.SelectedNode.Text
              Dim material as string = TreeMaterials.SelectedNode.Parent.Text

              dgvMaterials.Rows.Add(material, rodzajName, rodzajID)
End Sub
```

Tried also this:

```
Private Sub myButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddMatType.Click
Dim dt as DataTable
dt = New Variation().GetAll() 'returning Ids and Names
Dim cbo = CType(dgvMaterials.Columns(3), DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)
cbo.DataSource = dt
cbo.ValueMember = "Id"
cbo.DisplayMember = "Name"
Dim rodzajID as String = TreeMaterials.SelectedValue
Dim rodzajName as string = TreeMaterials.SelectedNode.Text
Dim material as string = TreeMaterials.SelectedNode.Parent.Text

dgvMaterials.Rows.Add(material, rodzajName, rodzajID)
End Sub
```

In both cases every time user clicks button row is added to datagrid but last column's combobox is empty. How to solve that?

Comment: If there is more than 1 DGV on the form, be sure you are accessing the correct one.  Otherwise, we know the data is in the items collection.  Make sure the user knows to click 2ce to open the CBO (first time just selects the row).  As a last resort, open the designer, remove the CBO column, save the project, then add it back in again - maybe you set some property by accident which prevents it from working.

Comment: ...for instance, if you have accidentally set the cbo column to ReadOnly in the columns editor it wont open

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line for asociate your comboBox to the wanted column :

```
  dgvMaterials.Columns.Insert(3, cbo)
```